# How to customize the users and groups in activiti

Tags: activiti, business-process-management

I am trying to use users and groups managed from other system. Users and groups are managed by a different application where we maintain the users and groups (Oracle DB). Now I need to use those users and groups . How can I achieve it? how can I change the  usermanager and groupmanager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overwrite the Identity Manager by creating custom UserManager and GroupManager factory classes as well as the specific impl classes that go with it.
I would use the activiti-ldap module as a template.

Once you have your factories, you register your custom session providers in your spring config file using the customSessionFactories stanza of the configurationFactory.

There is pretty god description in "Activiti in Action" or if you search customSessionFactories and Activiti in google you should find plenty of suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is replicate the data in your activiti tables. This can be done inserting in ACT_ID_USER, ACT_ID_GROUP and ACT_ID_MEMBERSHIP or using the API.
If the user and groups data are stored in a similar way in your Oracle DB and Activiti is also On Oracle, you can also replace these tables for materialiced views that refresh their data againts your source tables.